# Will an object resting on a rotating platform move in a frictionless world?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

Imagine that a pebble is placed on a uniformly rotating, frictionless disk.  What will happen to this pebble? Will the disk slide under it and the pebble stay as is? Or will there be a centrifugal force on the pebble and it'll be thrown off the disk?

Comment: Is there gravity?

Comment: Yup there is gravity, acting vertically downwards

Comment: @BrandonEnright I disagree.  How would your statement be different from saying that studying projectile motion in a uniform gravitational field with zero air resistance is nonsensical?  Idealizations are often very helpful in gaining conceptual insight.  Moreover, they are useful because real situations are often well-approximated by idealizations.  If we, for example, had a hockey puck on a rotating ice table, we could approximate the situation to which the OP refers pretty well.

Comment: @joshphysics You're right, I've retracted my comment.  I my initial reaction to the problem was that there would be a non-uniform electric field because atoms don't pack perfectly flat and this non-uniform field would still affect the pebble.  Then I realized this effect would be the same thing as friction which makes no-friction non-physical.  Instead to handle this problem you have to completely ignore atoms and just think of the problem in abstract perfect pebble, perfect disk terms.

Comment: @BrandonEnright Thanks for the edit. My question is more clearer. Now this raises another question. If the pebble in not thrown off, then that means water in a spinning bucket wont stick to the sides?

Comment: Coninued....
Now lets assume that there is friction. In this case the water will stick to the sides, wont it? Now according to Einstein, there is no way to judge if the bucket is rotating or the universe is rotating w.r.t bucket. Which one of them is 'real'. So even if the universe was rotating and the bucket was not, when viewed from the universe frame, the water will stick to the sides, wont it? Please point me wrong if I am. And I apologize for not being so clear.

Comment: @vardhanamdaga I think you should ask that as a separate question.  Also, make sure to include "@username" if you want people to see your replies.  I just happened to see your comment because I looked back at the question.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that this whole setup is being viewed from an inertial frame and that if there is gravity, then it points perpendicular to the plane of the disk, then

The disk will slide under the pebble, and the pebble will stay where it is.

Why?  Well in an inertial frame, Newton's second law holds.  Since the force on the pebble tangent to the surface of the disk is zero when there is no friction, the acceleration of the pebble will be zero.  Therefore, it's velocity will be constant, and if it's velocity started at zero, then it would remain zero for all later times.

Comment: So you say, that if a bucket of water rotates in a friction free environment then the water will not stick to the sides? It will stay where it is, and the bucket will go on rotating?

Comment: @vardhanamdaga A bucket of water is not even remotely related to a spinning disc. More details about how the bucket is rotating will help

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I think that's a bit harsh and not entirely a fair characterization.  If there were some liquid that had no interaction with the sides of the bucket, then yes, if you started to spin the bucket it would just sit there.

Answer (score 3):

In that case the pebble won't move.

If there is no friction, there won't be any forces between the pebble and the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Pebble will not move according to a inertial frame outside the disk which is rest with respect to ground,Since looking from this inertial frame,there is no horizontal force acting on pebble because of frictionless.Hence accoring to newton's $2^{nd}$ law pebble will stay in its state according to a observer from ground.
But for an observer rotating along disk$($non-inertial frame,we have to include pseudo force$)$  see that pebble is under centrifugal force acting on it and for his observation the pebble will move relative with him and dynamics given by newton $2^{nd}$ law,ie $ma=centrifugal force$

Comment: When working with rotating reference frames remember it's not just Centrifugal force you have to think about but also Coriolis force